# Angular pass a component from a module to another module in the App module

Tags: angular, module, components, ng-modules

I have an issue figuring out how I can pass a component from a module I import into my Angular application and use it inside another module that I import also in my App.

Note that all those two modules are modules I created.

That's my app.module.ts :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    PnDashboardComponent,
    PnFormulaireComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    LayoutModule.forRoot(environment.layout),
    DispoModule.forRoot(environment.dispoAides)
  ],
  providers: [
    ErrorsHandler,
    InitialisationService,
    InitializationGuard
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

What I want to do is pass a component let's say called `BreadcrumbComponent` from the `LayoutModule` to the `DispoModule` and beeing able to use it inside that module.

Note that LayoutModule and DispoModule are dependent angular module project that are packaged with ng-packagr and imported in my Application.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the export answer that is your way to go.

Comment: @Swoox it doens't work and I explained why in the comments

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a **`SharedModule`** and declare the **`BreadcrumbComponent`** in it. Also export the component so that i can be used across other Modules.

Import the SharedModule wherever you want to use BreadcrumbComponent in the application

Comment: I edited the question, I forgot to mention that the modules are dependent projects that where packaged and imported in my app, so I think your solution doesn't work in that situation

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do is pass a component let's say called `BreadcrumbComponent` from the `LayoutModule` to the `DispoModule` and beeing able to use it inside that module.

then write

```
exports: [
    BreadcrumbComponent
]
```

in your `LayoutModule`

and import `LayoutModule` in `DispoModule`

Comment: I can't import LayoutModule in DispoModule because I don't want to put the LayoutModule in the package.json of the DispoModule. I don't see the point of installing the whole package if I want only one component of it.